How to keep name in binary copy in Azure Data Factory on a SFTP server
I'm pretty new to ADF, I have a Blob storage configured for SFTP. On this Blob, I would like to copy files with the '.json' extension or another specific extension. I used Copy file activity and 2 binary dataset. For the source, I used a wildcard folder path and '*.json' for the file name. For the sink, I just used 'test' as the subfolder.
I am able to copy them, but I cannot keep their original names. How can I do that ?
name of the files
I tried to configure by variabilising, but maybe I did it wrong. I couldn't get the name of the files being copied
Pipeline json :
{
"name": "pipeline3_A",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Copy data1",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "BinarySource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "SftpReadSettings",
                        "recursive": false,
                        "wildcardFileName": "*.json",
                        "deleteFilesAfterCompletion": false,
                        "disableChunking": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "BinarySink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "SftpWriteSettings",
                        "copyBehavior": "FlattenHierarchy",
                        "operationTimeout": "01:00:00",
                        "useTempFileRename": true
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Binary1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Binary2",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "FileName": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}

}

Could you please provide your pipeline json?

@Bhavani done in the edit

According to your pipeline Json you are choosing Flatten hierarchy as Copy behavior in your sink. That may be the reason to get your file names shown below:

Make Copy behavior None in your sink as shown below:

Then after successful run of copy activity you will get the file names as shown below:

Here is the pipeline Json for your reference:
 {
    "name": "pipeline6",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BinarySource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "SftpReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "wildcardFolderPath": "ins",
                            "wildcardFileName": "*.json",
                            "deleteFilesAfterCompletion": false,
                            "disableChunking": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BinarySink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "SftpWriteSettings",
                            "operationTimeout": "01:00:00",
                            "useTempFileRename": true
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "sftpsrc",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "sftpsink",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}


thank's a lot !!
